# Debian 10 で celeryd パッケージがインストールできない

Tags: debian, celery

## 環境

VMware Workstation 15上の Debian 10

## やりたいこと

Debian10上でceleryd,celerybeatをサービスとして起動したい。

## やったこと

以下のようにインストールを試しましたが、"パッケージが見つかりません" という表示が出てしまう。

```
sudo apt install celeryd
```

仮想マシンですが、Webブラウザでインターネットにはつながっており、他のパッケージはインストールできています。

### Debianサイト

[celeryd_3.1.23-7_all.deb のダウンロードページ](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/celeryd/download)
このサイトのアジア[ftp.jp.debian.org/debian](http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/celery/celeryd_3.1.23-7_all.deb)
このリンクの「リンクのアドレスをコピー」して、WEBブラウザのアドレス部に直接入力すると、ダウンロードできました。
下記の画像のようにインストーラが表示されますが、インストールできません。

[image: celerydのインストール]

Comment: インストールの前に `apt search` でパッケージ名を確認してください。 https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=celery

Comment: 参考: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html

Comment: searchコマンドでも見つかりませんでした。

Comment: debianサイトから辿って、debファイルをダウンロードしましたが、インストールできないものでした。(https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/celeryd/download)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian Buster環境で実際に動かして確認したわけではありませんが、

- `celeryd` がDebianのパッケージマネージャで配布されていたのは Debian stretch までのようです

  - このバージョンは2017年6月に正式リリース、2020年と2022年にそれぞれ通常サポートとLTSが終了済みの古いもので、現在 `oldoldstable` とされている
  - スクリーンショットで提示されているのもそちらですが、 3.12.3と非常に古い `celery` のバージョンになっています（現時点での最新版は `5.2` ）
- ……ですので、 `celeryd` を実行したいならまず最新版の `celery` ( `python3-celery` )をインストールしてから、ドキュメントに従って `celeryd` や `celerybeat` の設定ファイルを作る必要がありそうです。

  - もし、この `celery==3.12.3` がプロジェクトの都合上必須である場合、古いライブラリをインストールできないDebianのパッケージマネージャではなく、 `pip` や `poetry` など Python側のパッケージマネージャを利用するべきでしょう。