# systemd-sysv-generatorでのサービス起動方法

Tags: debian, systemd, celery

## 環境

OS：Debian11
CPU:ARMv8（組み込みボード）

## やりたいこと

ARM系CPUボードでDebian10を使用している環境からの移植
celeryおよびcelerybeatを動作させたい。

### Debian10の環境

/run/systemd/generator.late以下に二つのファイルが存在する。

#### ./celeryd.service

```bash
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/celeryd
Description=LSB: celery task worker daemon
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/celeryd start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/celeryd stop
```

#### ./celerybeat.service

```bash
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/celerybeat
Description=LSB: celery periodic task scheduler
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/celerybeat start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/celerybeat stop
```

/etc/init.d以下に二つのファイルが存在する。

- celerybeat
- celeryd

/etc/default以下に二つのファイルが存在する。

- celerybeat
- celeryd
  この中の記述として、/usr/local/bin/celeryが実行ファイルでることが記述されている。

### Debian11への移植

上記の関連するファイルをすべて、同じ指定フォルダ以下に複製し、再起動。

```bash
# systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep celery
```

このコマンドに対して、
・celerybeat generatedで表示される。
・celeryd は表示されない。
また、/run/systemd/generator.late以下の celeryd が消えている。

## 質問内容

1. 一般的な/lib/systemd/system/*.serviceでのサービス登録とsystemd-sysv-generatorは何が違うのでしょうか？
2. 再起動後に/run/systemd/generator.lateから消える理由と追跡調査の仕方（対象のログの存在場所）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux でサービス (=デーモン) を管理する方法として、systemd と (古い) 伝統的な init.d とがあります。
最近の OS バージョンであれば基本的には systemd が採用されていますが、後方互換性のために init.d での管理も一部サポートされています。
両者はサービス起動用のスクリプトの配置先ディレクトリだけでなく、管理用のコマンドも異なっています。

[systemd-sysv-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-sysv-generator.html) は init.d 経由で起動するデーモンを systemd での管理ができるようラッパースクリプトを作成するもののようです。

---

あなたの [過去の関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/94463) を見る限り、celery は最新の debian ではパッケージとして提供されていないようなので、恐らく init.d 配下のスクリプトはあなたが自分で作成したものと思われます。その後 systemd-sysv-generator で systemd 向けの起動スクリプトを作成した…と推測されます。

ただ、同じく過去の質問のコメント欄で言及した [Celery のドキュメント](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) には init.d, systemd それぞれのサービス登録用のスクリプトが例として提示されています。

init.d 配下のスクリプトは整理して、systemd のユニットファイルを作成して管理する方がわかりやすいんじゃないかと思います。

---

`/run` ディレクトリは一般的に tmpfs = メモリ上に作成される一時的なファイルシステムで、OS 再起動時には削除されます。この下に恒久的なファイルを置くのは間違いです。

前述のドキュメントで [Service file:](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html#service-file-celerybeat-service) の項目を見ると、以下のパスに配置する例が記載されています。

```
/etc/systemd/system/celerybeat.service
```

参考:
[systemdのユニット定義ファイルは、どこに置けばいい？](https://kazuhira-r.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/06/06/210401)

Comment: /etc/init.d以下に配置したcelerydスクリプトの実行権限が適切ではなく、サービスの起動失敗になっていました。失敗すると、/run/systemd/generator.lateのファイルはガーベージされてしまうようです。